# Что такое постоянные морфологические признаки?

Tags: морфология

Что такое постоянные морфологические признаки? Изменил я глагол по числу - получил глагол такого же лексического значения? Что я получаю изменяя, например, глагол по постоянным или не постоянным морфологическим признакам? Какая будет между ними разница? Что такое формы слова?

Я раньше думал, что изменяя слово по изменяемым признакам, я получаю слово с тем же лексическим значением, которое сохранило постоянные признаки исходного слова. Может быть можете порекомендовать литературу? Пытаюсь по школьным учебникам, но теория как-то там не до конца сформулирована...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**МОРФОЛОГИЯ**,  [от греч. morphē форма и lógos ― учение] 2. Лингв. Раздел грамматики, изучающий **формы слов**.  **Морфологические признаки** ― это признаки, связанные с формой слова, они бывают постоянными и непостоянными.

Также существуют понятия **слово и словоформа**, разберем их на примере ***зеленая трава.***

**1) Трава** ― существительное. Это слово, представленное своей начальной формой.

**Постоянные** морфологические признаки не меняются, они одни и те же для данного слова: нариц., неодуш, ж.род, 1-е скл.

**Непостоянные признаки** ― число и падеж, существительное склоняется (изменяется) по числам и падежам: трава, травы, травой, травами и т.д.

Всё это словоформы, каждая имеет **конкретный падеж и число**.

В русском языке три склонения, поэтому в языке мы имеем **три набора падежных форм для ед. ч. и один  набор падежных форм для мн. числа** (с вариациями в И. п и Р.п.). Но конкретное существительное относится к определенному склонению, поэтому оно имеет **два набора падежных форм**: для ед. числа и мн. числа.

2) **Зеленый ― прилагательное.** Постоянные признаки: качеств., полное, непостоянные признаки: род, число, падеж. Мы видим, что **род уже относится к непостоянным признакам**, это значит, что прилагательное **изменяется по родам, падежам и числам.** У  прилагательного 4 набора словоформ.

**3) Непостоянные признаки для существительного и прилагательного задаются в словосочетаниях и предложениях,** например:

Дети бегают по траве. Глагол задаёт существительному Д.п., падежная форма **по траве** соответствует ед. ч., Д.п.

Дети бегают по зеленой траве.  Прилагательное согласуется с существительным в ж. роде, ед.числе и Д. падеже, для этого выбирается соответствующая падежная форма (словоформа).

Comment: А однокоренные слова - это обязательно словоформы?

Comment: Если постоянные признаки разные у двух слов(например вид у глаголов), то они разные? Верно? "шить", "сшить"

Comment: Нет, даже  трава и травка - это разные слова, у них разный морфемный состав и разные смысловые оттенки (суффикс К придает слову уменьшительно-ласкательное значение). И каждое слово имеет свой ряд словоформ: трава - траву - по траве, травка -травку- по травке.

Comment: Глаголы шить и сшить образуют видовую пару, и это разные слова. А вообще говоря, постоянные признаки являются скорее грамматическими, а не морфологическими признаками, так как они характеризуют всё слово, а не отдельные словоформы. Например, глагол сшить переходный совершенного вида. И все словоформы (сшить - начальная форма, сошью, сошьёт и т.д.) имеют эти признаки (переходность и совершенный вид).

Answer (score 2):

> Может быть, можете порекомендовать литературу?

Посмотрите [**"Часть 4. Морфология. Части речи и образцы их морфологического разбора"**](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part4.htm) в учебнике Литневской.

По-моему, очень хороший учебник. Приведён на портале [**Грамота.ру**](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php).

Comment: Спасибо, буду читать)